# Time complexity of the algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search

I wrote an algorithm for finding a key in sorted array of infinite integers.

```
 findKey(int k, int start, int end)
     int mid = (start + end)/2

     if (k < array[mid])
         findKey(k, start, mid)
     else if (k > array[mid])
         findKey(k, mid+1, end)
     else 
         return mid
```

I want to know the time complexity of this algorithm. Is it o(logn)? I'm really confused, can anyone explain? Also let me know if there are any flaws in here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "infinite integers"? And how is this any different from an ordinary binary search?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: The number of integers is unknown, assuming it as infinite.

Comment: Previous question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329937/search-algorithm-and-its-complexity) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196896/why-to-consider-binary-search-running-time-complexity-is-as-log2n). The first link talks about an /infinite/ array and  binary search.

Comment: If you are assuming the numbers can be infinitely large, then you can't assume that your arithmetic operators are O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Let we have array with stored value 
[image]

Suppose we want to find the key=20, we call findkey(20,1,8) with parameters k=20, start=1 and end = 8

**Series of function calls**

[image]

```
Recurrence relation :

T(n)  = T(n/2)+c
 expanding…
          =T(n/2^2)+c+c
          =T(n/2^3)+c+c+c

Kth time expanding…

          = c+c+c+c+c . .. .. . .. . . .  .T(n/2^k)

Let at kth time array size become 1,
we assume it as a base condition for recurrence.
Thus , 
   n/2^k = 1
      n  = 2^k
Taking log both sides ..
    log n = k

 time complexity of recurrence..

   T(n) = c* log n 
        = O(log n)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've made is the [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), or something close to it. This algorithm is O(log n).